# One of the values of my object should be an array of objects, but instead of pushing the inner object into the array it creates new ourter object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

I am trying to create an array of objects with the following stricture

```
obj {
name : name,
items : []
}
```

where items should be an array of item objects like this

```
item {
itemName : itemName, 
price : price
}
```

when I try to add a second item object to the array, it creates instead another of the outer object

```
function catalogue(input) {
    let catalogue = [];

    for (let line of input) {
        let [name, price] = line.split(" : ")
        let catalogueLetter = name[0];
        let obj = {
            name: name[0],
            items: []
        }

        if (!catalogue.includes(catalogueLetter)) {
            catalogue.push(obj)
        }
        let innerObject = {
            productName: name,
            productPrice: price
        }
        obj.items.push(innerObject)

    }
   }
}

catalogue([
    'Omlet : 5.4',
    'Shirt : 15',
    'Cake : 59',
    'Carrot : 2'
])
```

and I am getting this:

```
[
  { name: 'C', items: [ [Object] ] },
  { name: 'C', items: [ [Object] ] },
  { name: 'O', items: [ [Object] ] },
  { name: 'S', items: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

and I am trying to get this :

```
[
  { name: 'C', items: [ [Object1, Object2] ] },
  { name: 'O', items: [ [Object] ] },
  { name: 'S', items: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

Comment: `!catalogue.includes(catalogueLetter))` this will always be `true`. `includes` works like `===`

Comment: Frankly, I'd probably get rid of the name property and use the letter as the key: `[{C: [], O:{}, S:[]}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!catalogue.some(cat => cat.name === catalogueLetter)) {
  catalogue.push(obj)
}
```

instead of this:

```
if (!catalogue.includes(catalogueLetter)) {
  catalogue.push(obj)
}
```

`!catalogue.includes(catalogueLetter)` is always `true`, because `catalogue` is an array of objects and not array of strings.